# Generate AvroSchema From org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, apache-spark-dataset

I have a `DataSet<Row>` result set obtained from a Spark SQL JDBC query.

I can save it to the filesystem using `dataset.write.parquet(path);` But I also would want to get the avro schema for this recordset for some other purpose.

I am aware that there is a `dataset.schema()` method that returns `org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType`.

What I wouldlike to know is, how can I convert this `StructType` to `AvroSchema`?

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can either loop through the sql schemas and perform a type matching or use packages like e.g. the [spark-avro](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro) from databricks. This should be hat you need:
[Databricks SchemaConverters](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/blob/branch-4.0/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/avro/SchemaConverters.scala)
Take a look at the tests for example usages.